# I am getting a timeout error with urllib2 in Python

Tags: python, urllib2, web-crawler

I am building a crawler to get some data from a site. So far I'm only hitting up one URL to test out my code. The code I was using was working just fine for a while - now its giving me errors.

I'm just learning Python, so I'm not entirely sure what to do. I did try setting the socket timeout to 100, but that didn't change anything. Any ideas on how I can solve this?

This is how I am retrieving the HTML code:

```
project_html = urlopen(item).read()
```

Error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "linkscanner.py", line 76, in <module>
project_html = urlopen(item).read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 393, in open
protocol = req.get_type()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 255, in get_type
raise ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original
ValueError: unknown url type: h
```

Comment: This isn't a timeout error; it looks like you are giving it an invalid URL. Double check that you can access the URL in your web browser.

Comment: I am able to access the URL. I even tried feeding it "http://www.google.ca", and that gave me the same error.

Comment: Sorry, that was poorly worded. You need to include the protocol in the URL. Try `http://google.ca`

Comment: Actually, you are right. It was a stupid syntax issue. Thanks a lot!